# ggnet2 function in R only plots some groups, if the number of groups is larger than 5-6

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I have a data.frame with 3 columns, the first two are the network connections, the third is the group they belong to.

I want to plot these using ggnet2, but this only works well for numbers of groups 1-5, with more groups the plot simply does not display all of them.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks already!

```
network <- data.frame(source=NA,target=NA,group=NA)

net = network(network[,1:2], directed = FALSE)

net %v% "group" = as.character(network$group)

ggnet2(net, color = "group")

#the dput(head(network)) of an example looks like this (and this only plots two groups instead #of 10:

structure(list(source = structure(c(34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L), .Label = c("TRBV11-3*01,CASSLDSNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSARSTGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSGRATGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRSTGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGAYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGIYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGLYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGNYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGSYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGVYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGYYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSYEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSKRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSLRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSLRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSMRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSMRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSPRSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSQRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSRRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSRRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSSRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSTRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSVRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSYRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CATSGRSTGELFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGAGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGDGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSPRPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAEAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGDGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGGYTF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSAWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSAWYNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSGWDNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSGWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSGWHNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVFENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWANEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWDNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWNNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWSNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVWSNEQYF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWWNEQFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDAGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDEGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDGGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDHGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDLGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDMGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDPGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDQGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDRGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDRGGTEASF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDSGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDTGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEGSYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGTYEQFF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGTYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDLRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDMRGGTYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDQRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGPYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGSYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGTYEQFF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGVYEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSAGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSASGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSASGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSDSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFGGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSFSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFTGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSGGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSGSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSGSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSHSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSISGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYNEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLGGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLTGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSPAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGGYNEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSQSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSGRTGTDYEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSTSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSVGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSYSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSYSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTASGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTLGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTPSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTQSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTSAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTSSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTTSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTVSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV6-5*01,CASSYGNTEAFF", 
"TRBV6-6*01,CASSYGNTEAFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGKHNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGKYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGPYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRANEQYF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRHNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRLNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRMNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-6*01,CASSLAGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASIGSYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSASESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSFSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSHSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSISESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSLSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSNSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSPSESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSRSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASVGSYEQYF", "TRBV9*01,CASSATSGKSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSATSGRSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSSTSGRSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSTTSGRSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSVTSGRSNEQFF"), class = "factor"), target = structure(c(18L, 
54L, 65L, 87L, 70L, 80L), .Label = c("TRBV11-3*01,CASSLDSDEQFF", 
"TRBV11-3*01,CASSLDSEEQFF", "TRBV11-3*01,CASSLDSYEQYF", "TRBV11-3*01,CASSLDTNEQFF", 
"TRBV11-3*01,CASSLSSNEQFF", "TRBV11-3*01,CASSPDSNEQFF", "TRBV11-3*01,CASSRDSNEQFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSAGSYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSARATGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSARSSGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSARSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSARSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRATDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSGRATGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRAVGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSGRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSGRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIAGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIAGYNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIASSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGAHGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGAYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGIYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGLHGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGLYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGNYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGSHGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGSSGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGSYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGVNYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGVSGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIGVYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIGYYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIPGGYNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRASYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRATGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSADTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSAYEQFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSAYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSDYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSGYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSLDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSDEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSSEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSYEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSTDEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSIRTSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSISGGYNEQFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSISVYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSITGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSIVSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSKRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSLRATGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSLRSSGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSLRSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSLRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSLRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSMRSLYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSMRSSGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSMRSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSMRSSYGQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSMRSTGELFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSPRDSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSPRSSDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSPRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSPRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSQGSYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSQRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSQRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSRRSSGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSRRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSRRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRATGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRITDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSSRSAYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRSSGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSSRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSSRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTGIYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSTGSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTGSYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTGYYGYTF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSTRSADTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTRSAYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTRSSYEQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSTRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSTRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVAGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSVGLYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVRASGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVRSADTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSVRSAYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVRSSYEQYF", "TRBV19*01,CASSVRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CASSYGSYGYTF", "TRBV19*01,CASSYRSTDTQYF", "TRBV19*01,CATSGRSTDTQYF", 
"TRBV19*01,CATSGRSTGELFF", "TRBV19*01,CAVSRAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV27*01,CASAPRPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSERPYNEQFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGKGDGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGLGDGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGADAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGAEAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGAGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGASYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGDGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGGGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSFGQGWGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSFRPYNEQFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSLRPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSPRAYNEQFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGLGDGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQAGGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAEQYF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAGSFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAGYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGALAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAPAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGARAFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGASYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAVAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGAVYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGDGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGDYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGEAFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGGAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGGSYTF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGSEAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGSGYTF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYGQGTEAFF", 
"TRBV27*01,CASSYGQSAEAFF", "TRBV27*01,CASSYRPYNEQFF", "TRBV27*01,CATSLRPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSAWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSAWYNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSGFNNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSGWDNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSGWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSGWHNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSTFNNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVFENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVFHNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVVANEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWANEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWDNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVWENEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWNNEQFF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWSNEQFF", 
"TRBV29-1*01,CSVWSNEQYF", "TRBV29-1*01,CSVWWNEQFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSPEGSYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDAGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDEGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDGGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDHGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDLGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDMGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDPGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDQGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDRGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDRGGTEASF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDSGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQDTGGTEAFF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEASYEQYF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEGAYEQYF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEGNYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEGRYEQFF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-1*01,CASSQEMSYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-1*01,CASSSDRGGTEAFF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGSYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGTYEQFF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDKRGGVYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDLRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDMRGGTYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDQRGGPYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDQRGGTYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGLYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGPYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGSYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGSYTQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGTYEPYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGTYEQFF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGGVYEQYF", 
"TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDRRGTTYEQYF", "TRBV4-3*01,CASSQDSRGGPYEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CARSSGRSGTDYEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASAGSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASASSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASCASGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASIASGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASILSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASNLAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASNPAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSAAGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSAAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSAAGGYTEAFL", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSAEGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSAGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSASGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSASGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSASGSYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSDSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFAGGYTEAFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSFGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFGGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFSGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSFSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFSGSYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSFTGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSGAGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSGGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSGSGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSGSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSHSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSISGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGEYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGFTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYAEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYNEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYSEAFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYSEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGGYYEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLAGTYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLGGGYTEAFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGGFDEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGGFNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSGSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSLSSAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLTGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSLTGGYTEAFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSPAGGYAEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPAGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPGGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSPGRTGTDYEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGGYGEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGGYNEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSPSGSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSQGRTGTDYEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSQSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSRTGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSAGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSAGGYTEAFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSGRPGTDYEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSGRTGTDYELYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSGRTGTDYEPYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGAYYEQYF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSSGGYTEAFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSSTGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSTSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSVGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASSYSGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASSYSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTAAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTASGAYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTASGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTFGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTLAGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTLGGAYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTLGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTPSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTQSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTSAGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTSGGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTSGGGYNEQYF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTSSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTTSGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,CASTVGGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASTVSGGYNEQFF", "TRBV5-1*01,CASVAGGGYNEQFF", 
"TRBV5-1*01,FASSSGRTGTDYEHYF", "TRBV6-5*01,CASSAGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-5*01,CASSTGNTEAFF", 
"TRBV6-5*01,CASSWGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-5*01,CASSYGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-5*01,CASSYSNTEAFF", 
"TRBV6-6*01,CASSAGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-6*01,CASSTGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-6*01,CASSWGNTEAFF", 
"TRBV6-6*01,CASSYGNTEAFF", "TRBV6-6*01,CASSYSNTEAFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSATSGPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSGTSGPYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGIHNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGKANEQYF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGKHNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGKYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRANEQYF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRHNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRLNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRMNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRNNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRNNEQYF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGSLNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGTHNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSLTSGVYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSSTSGRLNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSVTSGPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-2*01,CASSVTSGRMNEQYF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSVTSGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-2*01,CASSWTSGPYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-7*01,CASSLAGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-8*01,CACSLAGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-8*01,CARSLAGRYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-8*01,CASSLAGRYNEQFF", "TRBV7-8*01,CASSLAGRYNEQFV", "TRBV7-8*01,WASSLAGRYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASIGDYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASIGNYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASIGSYEQYF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASLGSYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSASESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSFSDSSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSFSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSHSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSISESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSLSDSSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSLSESGYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSLSESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSNSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSPSEPSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSPSESSYNEQFF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASSPSEVSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASSRSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASTGSYEQYF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASTLSESSYNEQFF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASVGAYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASVGGYEQYF", 
"TRBV7-9*01,CASVGSYEQYF", "TRBV7-9*01,CASVISYEQYF", "TRBV9*01,CASGTTSGRSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSASSGKSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSATSGKGNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSATSGKSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSATSGKSTEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSATSGMSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSATSGRSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSATSGRSREQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSETSGRSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSGTSGRSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSPTSGKSNEQYF", "TRBV9*01,CASSSTSGRSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSSTSGSSNEQYF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSTTSGKSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSTTSGRSNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSVTSGKSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CASSVTSGRANEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSVTSGRNNEQFF", "TRBV9*01,CASSVTSGRSNEQFF", 
"TRBV9*01,CTSSSTSGSSNEQYF"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("tcns_10_tb_6174_a.txt", "tcns_11_tb_5433.txt", 
"tcns_12_tb_tb_6738.txt", "tcns_13_tb_8113.txt", "tcns_15_tb_6174_b.txt", 
"tcns_3_cd_tb8032.txt", "tcns_6_cd_tb_7180.txt", "tcns_8_cd_tb_5184.txt", 
"tcns_9_tb_8048.txt", "tcns14_tb_6825.txt"), class = "factor")), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So I don't know if that is the exact issue, but it seems that the function can only display a certain number of nodes/edges and if you put in more data points it simply omits them in an order I cannot quite figure out. Anyway, it seems to be an "amount of data points" behavior.